# How to sort files by modified timestamp in unix for a shellscript to pick them one at a time

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a shell script that picks one file at a time and processes them.
I want the script to pick files in the ascending order of their modified time.

I used the code below to pick .csv files with a particular filename pattern.

```
for file in /filepath/file*.csv
do
  #mystuff
done
```

But I expect the script to pick .csv files according to the ascending order of their modified time. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the file names don't contain any "strange" characters, e.g. newline, you could use the sorting capability of `ls` and read the output with a `while read...` loop. This will also work for file names that contain spaces.

```
ls -tr1 /filepath/file*.csv | while read -r file
do
    mystuff "$file"
done
```

Note this solution should be preferred over something like
`for file in $(ls -tr /filepath/file*.csv) ...`
because this will fail if you have a file name that contains a space due to the word-splitting involved here.

Answer (score 0):

with your loop "for"

```
for file in "`ls -tr /filepath/file*.csv`"
do
  mystuff $file 
done
```

Comment: This will not work if you have a file name that contains a space. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Answer (score 0):

You can return the results of `ls -t` as an array. (-t sorts by modified time)

```
csvs=($(ls -t /filepath/file*.csv))
```

Then apply your for loop.

```
for file in $csvs
do
  #mystuff
done
```